# Update title attribute of li in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a ul li list and I want to be able to rename the li element. Is there a way to change the title attribute of li. I tried a couple of things like the ones mentioned below but didnt work.

```
    $(this).attr("title") = $("#txtRenameSubCategory").val(); and 
   document.getElementById('#ul_li_SubCategories li.selSubCategories').title = $("#txtRenameSubCategory").val();
```

The html that is rendered looks like this.

```
<ul id="ul_li_SubCategories" style="width:200px;" class="chargeCapturetable margin0">
<li sequence="0" title="Category 1" class="liEllipsis selSubCategories" value="9"><a href="#"><span class="viewIcons delFaceName _delete fl"></span>Category 1</a></li>
<li sequence="1" title="Category 3" class="liEllipsis" value="11"><a href="#"><span class="viewIcons delFaceName _delete fl"></span>Category 3</a></li>
<li sequence="2" title="Category 4" class="liEllipsis" value="12"><a href="#"><span class="viewIcons delFaceName _delete fl"></span>Category 4</a></li><li sequence="3" title="Category 5" class="liEllipsis" value="13"><a href="#"><span class="viewIcons delFaceName _delete fl"></span>Category 5</a></li>
<li sequence="4" title="Category 6" class="liEllipsis" value="22"><a href="#"><span class="viewIcons delFaceName _delete fl"></span>Category 6</a></li>
<li sequence="5" title="test" class="liEllipsis" value="76"><a href="#"><span class="viewIcons delFaceName _delete fl"></span>test</a></li></ul>
```

Now eg. if I update at run time Category 1 to Category 101 I want to be able to update the same to the ul li list.

Comment: Answers below will sort you out, but for future reference, `getElementById()` doesn't require the `#` prefix.  Just pass it the ID ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added attr is wrong way 
try like

```
$(this).attr("title", $("#txtRenameSubCategory").val()); 
$('#ul_li_SubCategories li.selSubCategories').attr('title', $("#txtRenameSubCategory").val());
```

as per your comment

```
$('#ul_li_SubCategories li.selSubCategories a').html("<span class='viewIcons delFaceName _delete fl'></span>" + $("#txtRenameSubCategory").val());
```

Comment: Yes, this works. How can i change the display as well. I mean the "Category1" which is displayed in <a></a>. Changing this would also render change in UI.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the string as second parameter to [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2) to set the value of an attribute.

> Set one or more attributes for the set of matched elements.

```
$(this).attr("title", $("#txtRenameSubCategory").val());
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) should be used this way:

```
$(this).attr("title", $("#txtRenameSubCategory").val());
```

You need to give it in the parameter. And `.title` I am not sure if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give KEY,VALUE combination to `.attr()` function

```
$(this).attr("title","NEW TITLE");
```